# jsAnim: get object position

Tags: jquery, object, position

How to get object position in jsAnim or jQuery.. I just made when you click Right arrow my object to move 50px right. I want to get its new position and to make it move when you click n times right arrow till the end of the canvas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is you can retrieve miscellaneous positioning information using:

```
var rect = object.getBoundingClientRect();
```